# Windows 10 Enterprise questions

Tags: windows, windows-10

My personal W540 was a windows 7 Enterprise machine. Last year I upgraded to windows 10 Enterprise at the end of the free upgrade. When I bought the machine, I was back up with an image of the machine. So the upgrade is based on that image. Then I imaged it again for future use and I continue to use my Windows 7 OS. Yesterday, I restored the windows 10 Enterprise image. I found it takes about 70GB of space. After a long windows update, it takes about 110GB, some basic software included, such as 7zip, pdf reader and software from Lenovo but no office and other software.

I tried windows 10 Pro. It only takes 40GB of space.

My questions are the following.

1. Is there a way to clean up the windows 10 Enterprise?
2. I am a general software engineer, is there any advantage to using Enterprise but not Pro?

Comment: An upgrade is always going to occupy more space than a fresh install.  Have you ensured that you have run "Disk Cleanup" and included the System files option?  ***"enterprise" for a personal machine makes 0 sense.***  It is an add-on to pro to make it easier for IT to control your box.  I don't even think that you can buy it (as a person) as I believe that it's only license is a volume license managed through a domain controller.  If you want to save the space, a fresh copy of pro (not an upgrade) is the way to go.  Try WinDirStat as admin but it still won't show everything.

Comment: Have you used the built-in Disk Cleanup tool to remove the previous versions of Windows?

Comment: I restored the Enterprise image onto a new SSD drive. After restoring and updating, I cleaned up the machine with Disk Cleanup. Enterprise for personal machine makes 0 sense makes sense!